# Question about Fibonacci sequence generator - nothing prints

Tags: python, fibonacci

I was given an assigmnent in my class where I need to write an algorithm that can generate "n" numbers of the Fibonacci sequence.
I feel like this code should work, but am still having troubles locating what bug is preventing it from working.
The algorithm should start printing the Fibonacci sequence starting at the number `2` (the first 3 numbers are patched in), but it only prints the first 3 numbers and my algorithm doesn't print anything.
I even have sophisticated error checking that should rule out bad values, but it isn't reporting anything either.

```
#/usr/bin/python

import re
import math
import time
import sys

def errchk(hwmny,int1,int2,int3,int4,errcnt):
    #Sanity check; first 12 numbers don't have 6's
    expression = re.compile(r"^[^6]{1,3}", re.I | re.S) #expression for no sixes
    if expression.match(str(int3)):     # if it doesn't match
        return                      # return
    else:                           #otherwise
        if (hwmny > 12):        # as long as it's less than 12
            return          # no errors
        zints.err()         #but ifnot, errors
    return None

def nofloats():
    return math.floor(zints.int3)

class zeroints:
    int3=int4 = 0   #int3 and int4 are 0
    errcnt = 0  #count the number of errors
    def err(self):
        print "Errors"
        return

hwmny =15       #hwmny variable is 10
int1 =int2 =1       #int1 and int2 are 1
zints = zeroints()  #ints init'd to 0
print "0\n1\n1"

def loop(hwmny,int1,int2,int3,int4,errcnt):
    while(((zints.int4<hwmny)or not(zints.int4>0))and not(zints.int4==0)):  #while int4 is less than hwmny and error checking
        zints.int3 =int1+ int2          #int3 is int1 plus int2
        int1 =int2              #int1 is int2
        string = 'The Values Are'       #string is set to 'The Values Are'
        int2= zints.int3            #int2 is int3
        errchk(hwmny,int1,int2,zints.int3,zints.int4,zints.errcnt)
        print zints.int3            #print int3
        zints.int4= zints.int4+1        #int4 is int4 plus 1
        loop(hwmny,int1,int2,zints.int3,zints.int4,zints.errcnt)
        continue

loop(hwmny,int1,int2,zints.int3,zints.int4,zints.errcnt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fix looks simple.
The grouping in the while loop is wrong, change it to the following and it should work fine:

```
while((zints.int4<hwmny)or not(zints.int4>0)and not(zints.int4==0)):
```